# prematurely reaching EOF

Tags: c, eof

The read code is:

```
int Function(FILE fpi*, int *Ncols, int *Nrows) {
    if (fscanf(fpi, "%d", Nrows) > 0) {
        return fscanf(fpi, "%d", Ncols);
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", "EOF reached.");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

(note - Function is just a stand-in name). The file looks like:

```
2 2
1 1
1 1
3 3
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

It iterates through the first set of instructions fine - that is, it takes 2 and 2 and store them in Ncols and Nrows, and then does operations with the following 2 by 2 set of data (set of ones); however, upon reaching the end of the while loop in the main program:

```
int eof = Function(fpin1, &Rsize1, &Csize1);
while (eof > 0) {
    stuff

    eof = Function(fpin1, &Rsize1, &Csize1);
}
```

it just dies.

Comment: "just dies" is not specific enough. Hits EOF? Exits? Segfaults? Nasal demons?

Comment: Also, `FILE fpi*` is not valid syntax...

Comment: There are 2 `fscanf` in the `if` clause. It's likely to return eof at the second one since the first one may have read the last number.

Comment: You check whether `fscanf` fails and then assume that this is because it's reached EOF. Unless there is code that you aren't showing us?

Comment: how is FILE fpi* not valid syntax?

Comment: @TylerSebastian: Did you mean `FILE *fpi`?

Comment: It should be `FILE *fpi`. Otherwise, it wouldn't compile. FYI: your code as written above works for me; with the input file you gave, it reads two matrices (2x2 and 3x3). Check to make sure your matrix-reading code is reading the right number of entries.

Comment: yes, Charles - I copied it down wrong into SO.

Comment: Please always paste the _exact_ code that you are using. This saves people chasing red herrings.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: But even doing that won't make this question any more answerable. Much better to spend the time making this a complete and answerable question, IMHO.